# Having a Separate adapter for each recyclerview is considered as a bad practice?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, listview-adapter

So in my application, i have used so many recycler views. And i have created seperate viewholder/adapter for each view. Is this a bad practice? or should i consider having one model adapter/holder for all views?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your own thoughts? For example why did you create many adapters instead of expanding the one you started with? And what would you think if you had to change two RecyclerViews of ten?

Comment: Creating separate adapter for each recycler view depends on your requirements. if each adapter has different views and serves different purposes then it should remain  separate. It those as performing common tasks and have common views then use minimum number of adapters

Comment: ive got separate viewholders with different views. thats why i created new adapters/holders for each view.but then again i saw we can use a generic adapter.